# I receive an nginx error: "nginx.server failed" I need to understand how to fix this

Tags: nginx

I am trying to set up NGINX on Amazon Web Service... Ubuntu.

After I did this...

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /home/ubuntu/public_html;

    location /application1 {}
    location /images {
        root /home/ubuntu/data;
    }
}
```

I tried to restart NGNIX and I got this error

```
Job for nginx.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status nginx.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

Can anyone help a newbie know what to do next?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    root /home/ubuntu/public_html;

 location ^~ /images {
        alias /home/ubuntu/data;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /images/index.html;
        }


 location ^~ /application1 {
        alias /home/ubuntu/data;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /application1/index.html;
        }

}
```

Can I know which framework do you want to host